# How to detect which thread is holding the application from shut down in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm just wondering if there any way to detect an alive thread that is holding the application from shutting down properly in C#/.Net. Which means that after users close the application, its instance is still visible in the task manager.

Comment: Usually the one that holds the application instance is your startup form or page.

Comment: You can dump the process (using e.g. debugging tools for windows, process explorer or task manager (on modern versions of windows)), then open the dump in windbg, load SOS, and see what threads are in there. ([SOS Cheat sheet](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2009/06/30/sos-cheat-sheet-net-2-0-3-0-3-5.aspx))

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I got the list of the threads but I don't see any reason why thread pool threads hold the instance of the application.

Comment: If you have any windows open, the application won't shut down. I'v had the problem when using hidden non modal windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even I have a list of active threads, some of them cannot be traced because their call stacks are not available.

In addition, I just want to shut down the application gracefully. So I have made the following changes to my application.

**1. In App.StartUp()**

Set the shut down mode

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
              Current.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnMainWindowClose;
}
```

1. When users click a close button, call the following function

   Application.Current.Shutdown();

Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

i would run the program in debug mode in visual Studio. on closing GUI if the program is still running, i will pause my debug mode, this will tell where my program is at. For advance view when running your program in debug mode, goto DEBUG>Windows>Thread Window. This will show all the the threads your program has spawned.
[may be this can help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11457100/no-thread-window-visual-studio-2010-ultimate).

You will get a window like [this http://mscerts.programming4.us/image/201307/Debugging%20with%20Visual%20Studio%202010_7.jpg](http://mscerts.programming4.us/image/201307/Debugging%20with%20Visual%20Studio%202010_7.jpg)

for more information how to used Thread Window and how to debug multithreaded applications

1) [How to Used Thread Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w15yf86f.aspx)

2) [How to Debug a MultiThreaded Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb157784.aspx)

3) [Debug Multithreaded Applications in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164746.aspx)

Comment: Thank you. But after having the list of threads, how can I know which one is the culprit? In your example the thread 5188 may hold the application, and how can we trace to the source code which initialized it?

Comment: Sometime the call stack is not available

Comment: i have edited my answer, there is complete tutorials on how to debug multithreaded applications. In general you should not worry about the threads with call stack is not visible.

Comment: Have a look on this Jon Skeet's [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062527/how-to-kill-thread-on-exit) on Threads. this may also help.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to hit pause and it take you to section of code that is running.

Another option is to add break points at the end of functions and see which one doesn't get hit...

Answer (score 0):

You may save all created threads in a container such as **List** and check **IsAlive** and **ThreadState** properties during exiting.

Another option to not care about holding threads is to set the **IsBackground** property to **false** to them. Also if you use **ThreadPool** or **Task** your threads are always background threads and it's recommended to use these classes instead of creating **Thread** manually.

(By the way, more information about your application type and reasons of exiting would be useful.)

Comment: Hi there, All threads are background. To attach a thread to the monitoring list as you mentioned is impossible because the project is huge and has many modules. So I hope there is any debugging way to deal with.

Comment: May be it's possible to implement some kind of Factory pattern to create Threads. This Factory may store new instances in static field and you may achive it from any part of application.