# How can I view Threads window in Visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

In visual studio, it should be in Debug> Windows> Threads.
But mine doesn't have it!

[image]

Comment: You can try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11457100/no-thread-window-visual-studio-2010-ultimate

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You need to start debugging first, then it will appear in that menu.

Answer (score 30):

After you start debugging, go to `Debug=>windows=>Threads` or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to view threads.