# How to view active .Net events while stepping through code?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

How do I track what events are currently 'Active' or currently being handled while stepping through the code.

**The Issue**

While I was debugging code (stepping through it) within a rather large application, all of a sudden I found that the code that was being run was running through code in functions that had nothing to do with the code I was troubleshooting.  It took me a considerable amount of time to figure out why I found myself stepping through code in functions that were way outside the code I was debugging.

Turns out, at the start of the application, handlers are added to certain controls as well as timer controls.  The timer control triggers an event every 5 minutes or so.  There were other events being triggered when certain actions were taken, however I had no idea what was causing the debugger to enter into certain functions due to the fact that there was no indication or 'prompt' telling me an Event was Triggered and that was why I was now stepping into other functions.

How do I become aware of what is happening when events are triggered in the manner I mentioned above?

**Note**

This is not a question about how to add handlers or remove handlers in code.

Answer (score 1):

So basically timers are still running in the same thread as the main logic. every time a function/Event is done and the Window steps into the waiting part in which unser input is read and events are started, timers will trigger. they will not run while other events are busy. If you use Background Worker or start second threads. they will run in between you current steps and the visual studio will jump from one to another. there is a thread window to keep track of all active threads but this only gives a clue. sometimes its still annoying to jump from one to another function. My advice is to use a debugger-hidden attribute on those functions that keep on bothering you.

How to find the Thread window:

[How can I view Threads window in Visual studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38699234/how-can-i-view-threads-window-in-visual-studio)

How to use Debugger Hidden:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debuggerhiddenattribute?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2

and

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/cf20736c-cbfb-4919-b495-ea9a9235f9e5/debuggerhiddenattribute-example?forum=csharpgeneral